# How to subtract/add timzone difference in Snowflake

Tags: sql, date, datetime, timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have for eg : 2022-01-20 03:59:00.000 -0600

I wish to apply the offset to the entire timestamp. How do I do it in Snowflake. I my case, 6 hrs should be subtracted here to get the time in CST (without the offset)

Comment: When you see an offset after a timestamp, it means the date and time shown are *already* adjusted to the offset shown.  In the example you gave, 3:59 is the local time in a time zone with a UTC-6 offset, which happens to be the offset for US Central Time in effect at that date and time.  Thus, there's no conversion to perform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CONVERT_TIMEZONE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html) function:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('Zulu', '2022-01-20 03:59:00.000 -0600'::timestamp_tz);
```

If you want truncate the timezone part, you can convert TZ timestamp to NTZ timestamp using [TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html) function:

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('Zulu', '2022-01-20 03:59:00.000 -0600'::timestamp_tz));
```

Comment: May I ask the reason of adding "Zulu" ?

Comment: I chose a zone without time shifting, you can also use: Greenwich, UCT, Universal, UTC or any other from this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: To be clear, this answer shows converting from UTC-6 to UTC.  The OP asked about converting in the opposite direction, which is unnecessary since the timestamp is already in the desired offset.